# utc_current as default value in informix

Tags: informix

Use utc_current as default value in a field of an informix database table.
My idea is to do something like this, so that when that record is inserted or updated, the value is automatically increased since datetime or timestamp doesn't work for me.

```
CREATE TABLE tab1
  (
    id VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    update_ts  integer DEFAULT dbinfo('utc_current') ,
    modcount BIGINT,
  );
```

Comment: The expressions that can be used in a DEFAULT clause are very limited.  I strongly suspect that DBINFO is not one of them.

Comment: Default will not work for UPDATE. You need to use triggers to update the field on insert or update.